# Strategies to implement selective loading of plugins

Tags: plugin-development, performance

I'm trying to figure out some kind of mechanism to load plugins on demand, depending on the page url, to improve performance.

My primary concern is that I have some admin-ajax.php calls that are recurring while the user is active on the page. I tried profiling these calls, and discovered that the majority of plugins loaded for the ajax call were unnecessary.

While I could use `is_admin()` to identify an ajax call, I wish to leave WordPress and plugin code intact. Plus, `is_admin()` does not differentiate between an ajax call and admin panel.

I've been looking into the plugin loading procedure. I only saw `'muplugins_loaded'`, `'plugins_loaded'` actions, no filters to tap into the loading process. I checked `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins` and it appears the only way to change plugin loading is to `update_option('active_plugins')` explicitly, which is not a viable option. Other things are hard coded.

(I'd like to mention that this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/selective-loading/ use the `update_option` method, which in my opinion is only suitable in a non-ajax environment, or otherwise the option change wouldn't be atomic.)

I'm wondering if there was still some way to implement selective plugin loading?

Comment: Give that the selective-loading plugin bases the loading of the URLs to the site it should be viable to use with AJAX as well, might be wrong though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter `option_active_plugins`. You can change the result of `get_option()` here without actually changing the database.

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
    add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugins_temporary' );

function disable_plugins_temporary( $plugins )
{
    // unset plugins you don't need, then

    return $plugins;
}
```

#### Background

`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` calls `get_option( 'active_plugins', array() )` to get the active plugins. In `get_option( $option, $default = false )` we find this filter:

```
return apply_filters( 'option_' . $option, maybe_unserialize( $value ) );
```

So the resulting name for our filter is `option_active_plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you with your ajax call, but [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/plugin-organizer) is a well-supported plugin that enables the selective loading of other plugins based on URL. It works great on my site.