# option_active_plugins filter not working

Tags: filters

I added a filter for option_active_plugins to keep most plugins from loading on an admin page. Confirmed to be on the right page and to be returning a properly altered array, but it's having no effect on which plugins are being included on the page.

Tried high numbers for filter priority. No effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Where/how are you adding the filter? Post you code please and state which file the code is in.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97931/73)?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. It doesn't work in my own plugin, and it doesn't work in the plugin-organizer plugin either.

Comment: Have you already noticed the "edit" link at the bottom of your question?

Comment: My apologies for the lack of info. Will post an answer when time is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, duh: I needed to have my plugin in the /mu-plugins dir to make its filter available early enough for `function wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()`.

Comment: I have some problems also putting the file in that folder.. can you have a look here?
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240215/trying-to-disable-plugins-doenst-work