# Trying to disable plugins doens't work

Tags: plugins, php

I've developed a small plugin which empties the `$plugin` variable. And put it into the /mu-plugins folder. But it doesn't work.

What am I missing? The plugin is executed.

If I do a print_r on $plugin it contains all the name of the plugins of my Wordpress installation.

The plugin code is:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if($uri == "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php")
        {
            for($i=1; $i < count($plugins); $i++ ) 
            {
                {
                    unset( $plugins[$i] );
                }
            }   
        }

        return $plugins;
```

===========

This is the whole code

```
<?php

    class DisablePlugins {
    var $namespace = "disable-plugins";
    var $version = '1.0.0';

    /**
     * Instantiation construction
     * 
     * @uses add_filter()
     */
    function __construct() {
        // Directory path to this plugin's files
        $this->dirname = dirname( __FILE__ );
        // Rules configurations directory
        $this->rules_dirname = $this->dirname . '/' . $this->namespace . '-rules';

        $this->siteurl = get_option( 'siteurl' );
        $siteurl_http_host = parse_url( $this->siteurl );
        $this->siteurl_http_host = $siteurl_http_host['host'];

        add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', array( &$this, 'option_active_plugins' ), 1000, 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Initialization function to hook into the WordPress init action
     * 
     * Instantiates the class on a global variable and sets the class, actions
     * etc. up for use.
     */
    function instance() {
        global $DisablePlugins;

        $DisablePlugins = new DisablePlugins();
    }


    /**
     * Hook into WordPress option_$option filter
     * 
     * Get processed array of active plugins being loaded for a view to allow filtering
     * based off of a user's preferences
     */
    function option_active_plugins( $plugins ) {
        $rules = $this->load_rules();
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if($uri == "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php")
        {
            for($i=1; $i < count($plugins); $i++ ) 
            {
                {
                    unset( $plugins[$i] );
                }
            }   
        }

        return $plugins;

    }
}

// Initiate the DisablePlugins class
DisablePlugins::instance();
```

Comment: Could be a lot of things.  What triggers your code and when?

Comment: Is the code in a function triggered by a hook? Where does the value of $plugins come from? What happens to the returned value?

Comment: yes, I think it's triggered by an hook (I've posted the whole code). The returned variable shouldn't be deallocated.. I modify the values inside without reassigning it..

Comment: @jdm2112: it's inside the /mu-plugins folder

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook: have you got any suggestion?

Comment: You don't think `$rules = $this->load_rules();` might be halting the script with an undefined function error?  Have you checked for PHP errors?

Comment: The `instance()` function references a hook to WP's init action but that statement appears to be missing.  As it is, this plugin does not appear to actually do anything.

Comment: @jdm2112: but the instance function is calles as the last line? Or not?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook: thanks! this may be the problem. Tomorrow I will check if it's a copy and paste mistake or the real issue.

Comment: Correct.  The last line instantiates the class so the constructor fires, sets a few values, and hooks a callback function `option_active_plugins()` to a filter that doesn't exist, in WordPress anyway.  Constructor finishes and nothing happens.  I think we've found the problem.

Comment: @jdm2112: how can I correct the code? Can you answer it? I would really appreciate a lot!!

Comment: Where did this `DisablePlugins` class come from?  I'm guessing it is part of a larger project of some kind.  In order to make it "work" one would need to know what the intended behavior is.  Obviously disabling plugins is the goal, but where and when?  Triggered how?

Comment: @jdm2112: This is the original file: https://we.tl/sUMP7ARvLS

Comment: I don't get a file download with that URL.  I would suggest contacting the plugin publisher for help with this.